# How to extract only needed tag value from Dom Document in java?

Tags: xml, dom

The following response I had from salesforce describeSObject request as a String,

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<soapenv:Header>
    <LimitInfoHeader>
        <limitInfo>
            <current>73</current>
            <limit>15000</limit>
            <type>API REQUESTS</type>
        </limitInfo>
    </LimitInfoHeader>
</soapenv:Header>
<soapenv:Body>
    <describeSObjectResponse>
        <result>
    <activateable>false</activateable>
            <childRelationships>
                <cascadeDelete>false</cascadeDelete>
                <childSObject>Account</childSObject>
            </childRelationships>
    <compactLayoutable>true</compactLayoutable>
            <createable>true</createable>
            <custom>false</custom>
            <customSetting>false</customSetting>
            <deletable>true</deletable>
            <deprecatedAndHidden>false</deprecatedAndHidden>
            <feedEnabled>true</feedEnabled>
            <fields>
                <name>Id</name>
                <nameField>false</nameField>
            </fields>
            <fields>
                <name>IsDeleted</name>
                <nameField>false</nameField>
            </fields>
            <name>Account</name>
            <recordTypeInfos>
                <name>Master</name>
            </recordTypeInfos>
            <supportedScopes>
                <label>All accounts</label>
                <name>everything</name>
            </supportedScopes>
            <supportedScopes>
                <label>My accounts</label>
                <name>mine</name>
            </supportedScopes>
            <supportedScopes>
                <label>My team's accounts</label>
                <name>team</name>
            </supportedScopes>
        </result>
    </describeSObjectResponse>
</soapenv:Body>
```

From above response, I have to extract the value from describeSObjectResponse/result/fields/name tag and put it in the String array. When I have tried like below I got the value from all the name tags. Can anyone help me to overcome this.

```
public static Document loadXML(String xml) throws Exception
{
    DocumentBuilderFactory fctr = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder bldr = fctr.newDocumentBuilder();
    InputSource insrc = new InputSource(new StringReader(xml));

    return bldr.parse(insrc);
}

public static List<String> getIdFromXml(String xml, String tagName) throws Exception {
    Document xmlDoc = loadXML(xml);
    NodeList nodeList = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("name");
    List<String> ids = new ArrayList<String>(nodeList.getLength());
    for(int i=0;i<nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
        Node x = nodeList.item(i);
        ids.add(x.getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
    }
    return ids;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found a way to extract needed tag value like below,

```
public static Document loadXML(String xml) throws Exception
{
    DocumentBuilderFactory fctr = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder bldr = fctr.newDocumentBuilder();
    InputSource insrc = new InputSource(new StringReader(xml));

    return bldr.parse(insrc);
}

public static List<String> getInnerTagFromXml(String xml, String tagName) throws Exception {
    Document xmlDoc = loadXML(xml);
    xmlDoc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

    NodeList nodeList = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("fields");
    List<String> ids = new ArrayList<String>(nodeList.getLength());

    for (int temp = 0; temp < nodeList.getLength(); temp++) {
        Node nNode = nodeList.item(temp);
        if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
            ids.add(eElement.getElementsByTagName("name").item(0).getTextContent());
        }
    }
    return ids;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this XML data that is returned changes with each request. I mean the content can change but does the nodes change??
If not you can create a Bean class for the whole XML and then use JAXB to set the bean class. This way you can get any value you want.

Comment: Yes, It may be changing for the different sObject type. This response is for Account type.

Comment: Yes, I mean this only.. So for Account type the response nodes are same. That means you can create a bean class and then unmarshall this XML..